# Migrating from Socket.io to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, safari, socket.io, firebase-cloud-messaging

We currently have a hodgepodge of messaging systems.  For mobile we were using Ionic Push cloud service, and for desktop we are using socket.io+desktop notifications. We recently moved our mobile push notifications to Firebase cloud messaging.  We want to move our desktop notifications as well.  From the docs, it seems like FCM works with recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.  Safari supposedly supports push via APNs.

Is it possible for FCM to use the existing desktop notifications for push?

Or maybe I can use FCM just to retrieve push notifications across all browser and then use the desktop notifications libraries myself to display the message.  I'm just a little confused by the landscape of types of pushes to browsers and desktops.